# can't download cookie protected file with python

Tags: python, cookies, download, session-cookies, urllib2

All day long I'm looking to solve this. 
There is this http://www.some.site/index.php that is requesting user and password + sends cookie. Alright, I get in like this:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, os
import re # not required here but tried it out though
import requests # not required here but tried it out though
username = 'somebody'
password = 'somepass'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
resp = opener.open('http://www.some.site/index.php', login_data)
print resp.read()
```

The problem is that in the middle of the screen there is a link to download an .xls file: http://www.some.site/excel_file.php?/t=1303457489. I can download the file in any Browser (Mozilla, Chrome, IE) but not with Python. After the .php the **post data** ( ie: ?t=1370919996 ) is changing all the time when I login or Refresh the page.

Maybe I'm wrong but I believe the Post Data is generated from the cookie (or session-cookie), but the cookie contains only this: `('set-cookie', 'PHPSESSID=9cde55534fcc8e136fcf6588c0d0f1df; path=/')`

This is one way I tried to save the file:

```
print "downloading with urllib2"
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.some.site/excel_file.php')
data = f.read()
with open("exceldoc.xls", "wb") as code:
    code.write(data)
```

if I save it or if I print it out gives the same bad request error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function FetchRow() on a non-object in <b>http://www.some.site/excel_file.php</b> on line <b>112</b><br
```

**How can I download this file with Python?** Thank you so much in advance for any help!

There are many similar posts, I've checked them and my examples are inspired from those yet nothing worked for me. I'm not very familiar with [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), php, js.

EDIT: this is what I get when I print out the content of index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SOMETITLE</title>
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0.5)">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='somesite.css'>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- JavaScript hiding

function clearDefault(obj) {
    if (!obj._cleared) {
                obj.value='';
                obj._cleared=true;
    }
}

// -->
</SCRIPT>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="1000" height="150" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="16" cellspacing="0" class="header" style="background: #989896 url('images/header.png') no-repeat;">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle">
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="380">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                  <div id="login">
                       <form name="flogin" method="post" action="/index.php">
                      <h1>Login</h1>
                      <input name="uName" type="text" value="Username:" class="name" onfocus="clearDefault(this)">
                      <br>
                      <input type="password" name="uPw"  value="Password:" class="pass" onfocus="clearDefault(this)">
                      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="OK" class="submit">
                    </form>
                  </div>                                                                
                                                                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
                </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By post data your mean that t= GET parameter? That looks to be a unix timestamp (import time; time.time()), maybe that helps?

Comment: yes, by post data I mean the ?t=1322376525 stuff, it changes all the time. I've checked the source code of the site. No help, or nothing that I could interpret.

Comment: @Blubber it unix timestamp. I've managed to convert it but other then at least I know what that is I don't know if it's any other help. I try to call the file with it though :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to parse the response from the first code section and use the extracted url with the same `opener`. Without knowing the actual format of the link:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, os
import re # going to use this now!

username = 'somebody'
password = 'somepass'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
resp = opener.open('http://www.some.site/index.php', login_data)
content = resp.read()
print content

match = re.search(
    r"<a\s+href=\"(?P<file_link>http://www.some.site/excel_file.php?t=\d+)\">",
    content,
    re.IGNORECASE
)

assert match is not None, "Couldn't find the file link..."

file_link = match.group('file_link')
print "downloading {} with urllib2".format(file_link)
f = opener.open(file_link)
data = f.read()
with open("exceldoc.xls", "wb") as code:
    code.write(data)
```

Comment: the trouble is that the first code section doesn't extract the link. I think it is hidden within javascript. any further idea? I appriciate your effort so far.

Comment: @Laci Not many without taking a look at the content. Are you sure the `t` is required? Have you tried the suggestion in the comments about creating your own timestamp and using that? Have you tried to combine the 2 code segments and use the same `opener` for both instead of `urllib2.urlopen` so that the cookie is reused?

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I've updated the question with the content of index.php (first print in your solution). Unfortunatelly I get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/filexample.py", line 16, in <module>
    assert match is not None, "Couldn't find the file link..."
AssertionError: Couldn't find the file link...`

Comment: @Laci, that just means that the regex couldn't find the link

Comment: I understand, but that's a problem I think. I try to work around somehow with your example.

Comment: @Laci, I saw your edit. Are you sure you are successfully logging in? If you see that, I would guess that the login didn't work. Normally you would either get redirected to a different page or at least different content would be rendered after successfully logging in... from the source, it looks like you need to change `{'username' : username, 'j_password' : password}` to `{'uName' : username, 'uPw' : password}`

Comment: You are genious compered to me. That was the solution. I can't believe it was so obvious. Thank you so much! It worked. I have the content. It was this last comment of yours together with your solution script. THANK YOU not just for the solution but also for your time given for this!!!

Comment: @Laci No problem, glad I was able to help.